# In search of a Terminal App that works with SSH to AWS (EC2)

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have the itch to try and see how far down [this path](http://yieldthought.com/post/31857050698/ipad-linode-1-year-later) I can get for my own work. I've got a Galaxy Tab 10.1 and a Bluetooth keyboard.

I created an AWS EC2 Micro Instance and I can SSH into it from my laptop. I copied the key to the tablet and when I try to run the same SSH I get the error:

> ssh: Exited: String too long

[Here's a post where someone seems to be having a similar problem.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=309418) I'm not specifically using dropbear, that I know of, though. I've tried 3 or 4 different Android terminal clients and all seem to have this same problem. I do have busybox installed, so maybe it's using dropbear under the hood -- I just don't know.

I have been able to connect using [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) and the ssh key file downloaded from AWS, but the UI/UX for this app is horrible and unintuitive, and if this is my only option then I'd give up. It seems to be designed for phones, has no landscape orientation support, and only connects to the EC2 instance intermittently.

I also tried creating my own key files (`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -C GTab -t rsa -f id_rsa_gtab` on my laptop) and installing them on the EC2 instance & tablet, but get the same error. I tried running `ssh-keygen` from the tablet, but it doesn't appear to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh). It works perfectly and manages all connections and files in a secure way.

Comment: With Ubuntu I am unable to skip the request for a password

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ConnectBot](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=terminal&fdid=org.connectbot).

`An SSH and telnet client, and terminal emulator for local shell. Supports multiple sessions, including running them concurrently.`

Comment: This is the client I use when I want to ssh to some server. It supports public/private keys, and it also does port forwarding if you need it. And you can even generate the ssh key within the app itself, without needing to first create it on the computer and import it to the android system (saves time and hassle)

Answer (score 0):

Since this shows up in some searches I might as well throw this answer in.
I use Better Terminal Emulator Pro as it has better support for things like the Asus TF300 with the dockable keyboard. Including supporting the tab key that others sometimes have issues with. It does cost money though.
It does support ssh keys though they do have to be converted since it uses dropbear (as many others appear to) as the backend.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to convert the ssh keys? That sounds like really useful information.